# Hwo to create instace of predefined class with useState

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

There is a predefined class in Stripe to capture BillingDetails, as follows:

```
import { CardField, useConfirmPayment, useStripe, BillingDetails } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
```

I want to create instance of BillingDetails like this:

```
<CardField
            postalCodeEnabled={true}
            placeholders={{
                number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
            }}
            cardStyle={{
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                textColor: '#000000',
            }}
```

I couldnt find how to do it, Other way I tried was:

```
<TextInput
                    placeholder="Name"
                    value={billingDetails.name}
                    onChangeText={(name) =>
                    setBillingDetails((prevDetails) => ({ ...prevDetails, name }))
                    }
                />
```

Here the issue is:

```
const [billingDetails, setBillingDetails] = useState(new BillingDetails());
```

its throwing Cannot read prototype of undefined.

Question is, How do I create instance of BillingDetails with state management ( useState ).

Ref. https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/index.html

Answer (score 0):

[BillingDetails](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/src/types/Common.ts#L1C8-L1C8) is an interface and you can't use `new` keyword to create an instance of it.

You can create an instance of `BillingDetails` with it conformed property names. For example:

```
const [billingDetails, setBillingDetails] = useState({
  email: ...;
  phone: ...;
  name: ...;
  address: ...;
});
```

Since all properties are optional, you also create with an empty object

```
const [billingDetails, setBillingDetails] = useState({});
```

Comment: In the example you provided, you are not creating an instance out of BillingDetails (Interface), You have created an anonymous object with same properties as BillingDetails {emailL...etc} but you have not used BillingDettails Interface anywhere, even to declare. In second code "const [billingDetails, setBillingDetails] = useState({});" It appears it has nothing to do with BillingDetails. Basically I can use any name like: onst [bill, setBill] = useState({}); And it would still work

Comment: What I am trying to say is what is the purpose of Stripe giving these BillingDetails, Address interfaces then.

Comment: I am getting 'undefined is not a function' with your code - just reran the application after change.